# On Slime Load , change default package from Cl-USER

Tags: common-lisp, slime, ccl

When we start slime, it starts in CL-USER by default. Since I work with a particular package very frequently, I want to automatically in-package into that package on slime startup.
i.e. I want save myself the trouble of doing the below:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :my-package)
CL-USER> (in-package my-package)
MY-PACKAGE>
```

I tried putting the following code in my ccl-init.lisp file but the in-package did not work:

```
(ql:quickload :my-package)
(in-package my-package)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably could do something with `slime-repl-mode-hook`

But I think it would be better to use the `slime-sync-package-and-default-directory` which is bound to `C-c ~` and syncs your REPL to the package of your buffer.